# Min and Max Values

Tags: java

I have to make code to find the max, min, and average of grades. This is what I have so far:

```
public class test
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
double  average, count = 0, sum = 0, grades, max=0, min=0;
final int = MAX_GRA = 0
final int = MIN_GRA = 0

Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.print ("Enter the grades (999 to quit): "); //Taking input from the user
grades = scan.nextInt();

while (grades != 999) //A while loop that doubles count and adds the sum to grades
  {
  count++;
  sum += grades;

  System.out.println ("The sum so far is " + sum);
  System.out.print ("Enter the grades (999 to quit): ");

  grades = scan.nextInt();
  }

System.out.println ();

if (count == 0) //An if statement that identifies if no numbers were entered
System.out.println ("No grades were entered.");

else //An else statement that computes that computes the average
  {
  average = (double)sum / count;
  DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat ("0.##");
  System.out.println ("The average grade is " + fmt.format(average));
  }
 }   
}
```

Any ideas? I'm new to java and coding in general. Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you have a specific problem with the code then please state that, otherwise if you want someone just to review your code then you probably want it in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/  as it would be off topic here.

Comment: @mbomb007 Yes it is. I didn't completely understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
int maxGrade = 0;
int minGrade = 10; // Set the highest possible grade.

while (grades != 999)
{
    // If the current grade is greater that the maxGrade,
    // set this value the maxGrade.
    if(grades > maxGrade) 
        maxGrade = grades;

    // If the current grade is less than the minGrade,
    // set this value to the minGrade.
    if(grades < minGrade)
        minGrade = grades;
    // Here you will place the rest of your code. 
}
```

Note: Try to use more meaningful names for your variables. This will make your code more readable and it convey far easier your intentions and thoughts to the reader of your code. For instance, since `grades` would keep the value of the current `grade`, it would be more reasonable to name it as `grade`.

**Update**

As correctly laune mentioned below you could make use of two methods of `Math` class, in order to avoid the `if` statements.

```
while (grades != 999)
{
    maxGrade = Math.max(maxGrade, grades);

    minGrade = Math.min(minGrade, grades);
}
```

Comment: Even so - line 1 and 2 can't be correct.

Comment: @laune why so? Could you please explain it. Thank you

Comment: @laune Actually, I found my mistake. (Thanks, I am at least novice in JAVA).

Comment: Added the semicolons. Might have uses Math.min and Math.max.

Comment: @laune Thank you. I will mention your comment.

Comment: Setting minGrade = 10 might not work if the grades were on a scale of 100 and the smallest grade anyone got was, say, 55. Would you consider setting maxGrade = Integer.MIN_VALUE and setting minGrade = Integer.MAX_VALUE? This would be more correct in more circumstances.

Comment: I tried that. This is the error I received.

Comment: @ventus300 note that you should not use the `final` keyword for both of those variables. I assume that you overlooked this. So please try to remove the `final`, compile your code and run it again. Thanks

Comment: @Christos My bad! I did completely overlook that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would change somethings in the original code, and put like this.

```
public class Grades {

    // MODIFIERS (final, private, protected, static, etc.) type (int, double,
    // float, Object, etc.) name [= initialValue];
    private final static double END_GRADES = 999;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double count, sum, grades, max, min;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Initialized data.
        count = 0;
        sum = 0;
        max = 0;
        min = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter next grade ("+(int)END_GRADES+" to quit):");
            grades = scan.nextDouble();

            if (grades != END_GRADES) {

                if (count == 0) { // First grade is always min.
                    min = grades;
                }

                sum = sum + grades;
                count++;
                System.out.println("The sum so far is: " + sum);

                if (max < grades) { // New max??
                    max = grades;
                }

                if (min > grades) { // New min??
                    min = grades;
                }
            }

        } while (grades != END_GRADES);

        if (count != 0) {
            System.out.println("The average grade is: " + (sum / count));
            System.out.println("The max grade is: " + max);
            System.out.println("The min grade is: " + min);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No grades were entered.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like you took half the way to the answer, but I assume you are missing the **min**,**max** values as you average and sum are already computed.

First you need to add two instruction to update your maximum and minimum variables grade holders and the short way to do is to use:

- `Math#max` shorthand comparison returning the max of arguments.
- `Math#min` shorthand comparison returning the min of arguments.

But you have to remove the `final` modifier in front of the `MAX_GRA` and `MIN_GRA` because those instance variables need to be update at each iteration in your `while` loop so that they get either the user entered grade or keep their own value.

You should then take care of variables declaration, so that comparisons will take place and to do so, you can set the min value to the maximum possible one in the integer range and vice vers ça.

Last you need to add print statement simply to show you max / min value along with your average of grades:

```
public class MinMaxAndAverageCalculator
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    double  average, count = 0, sum = 0, max=0, min=0;
    int MAX_GRA = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int MIN_GRA = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int grade;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print ("Enter the grades (999 to quit): "); //Taking input from the user
    grade = scan.nextInt();

    while (grade != 999) //A while loop that doubles count and adds the sum to grades
    {
      count++;
      sum += grade;
      MAX_GRA = Math.max(grade, MAX_GRA);
      MIN_GRA = Math.min(grade, MIN_GRA);
      System.out.println ("The sum so far is " + sum);
      System.out.print ("Enter the grades (999 to quit): ");
      grade = scan.nextInt();
    }

    if (count == 0) //An if statement that identifies if no numbers were entered
    {
      System.out.println("No grades were entered.");
    }
    else //An else statement that computes that computes the average
    {
      average = (double) sum / count;
      DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat ("0.##");
      System.out.println ("The average grade is " + fmt.format(average));
      System.out.println ("The maximum grade is " + MAX_GRA);
      System.out.println ("The minimum grade is " + MIN_GRA);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty new to Java and this really helped. I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to be in help :) For sure you can accept the answer and upvote if it helped solving your problem ;)